# How do I automate storing user-inputed data in separate files so that it can be displayed to other users?

Tags: php

I've tried to get the post id for each post but the content is not appearing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**index.php**

```
<?php

   include 'main.php';
   include 'dbconnect.php';

   $findPosts = "SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY Date DESC";
   $showPosts = mysqli_query($db, $findPosts) or die(mysqli_error);

   while ($currentrow = mysqli_fetch_array($showPosts)) {

       //echo each post title as a link contained in a div box.//
       echo '<div class="box">';
       echo '<a href="view_post.php" class="PostTitle">'.$currentrow['Title'].'</a>';
       echo '<p class="Date">'.$currentrow['Date'].'</p>';
       echo '</div>';
   }
?>
```

The target attribute of each link is **view_post.php**

```
<?php

  include "dbconnect.php";
  include "main.php";

  $post_id = $_POST['ID'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE ID = '".$post_id."' LIMIT 1"; 
  $res = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
  if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {

      //Echo a table containing each post's title, content and date.//
      echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'><div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['Title']."<br /> 
  -".$row['Date']."<hr />".$row['Content']."</div></td><td width: '200px' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
  User Info Here</td></tr><tr><td colsplan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";

  } else {
      echo "<p>This post does not exist.</p>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I strongly encourage you store the data in a database instead. But if you want to go the file route you should consider using some of the same approaches. When you create a new post, create a unique id (traditional sql uses an incrementing number) and save the post using that id.

Comment: Why would you create new files containing every new questions instead of just doing a SQL query , get the question from the DB , and show it to the user ?

Comment: @JimL he already store it in a DB o.o

Comment: You don't need to create one page for each question, simply create a page and get he POST ID as a parameter and query it in the database then. Take this page here for example. This question is not in a single page, the page is only one, the question and it's information are all in the database, they are then set via the parameters in the url. Your question for example has the id `36019000`. That's how they get it from the database.

Comment: @SamyQc oh - I just read the text and saw no reason to check out the code - bummer ^^ I agree with the other posters though, no reason to use any files

Comment: Does this code not work as expected?  Why are you outputting this data to a file anyway?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do or what is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: Thanks @PhiterFernandes. I've edited the OP to show my updated code - I'm struggling to get the content to appear. Do I need to assign a post id manually using a hidden input in the post-submission form?